# NameError: name 'text_column' is not defined, Syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax, xgboost, nameerror

I am trying to run this XG Boost model for text classification, however I am running into the problem of defining. Here is my code:

```
def preprocess(text_column):

    """
    Function:    This function aims to remove links, special 
                 characters, symbols, stop words and thereafter 
                 lemmatise each word in the sentence to transform 
                 the dataset into something more usable for a 
                 machine learning model.
    Input:       A text column
    Returns:     A text column (but transformed)
    """
new_review = [] 
for review in text_column:
    text = re.sub("@\S+|https?:\S|[^A-Za-z0-9]+",'',str(review).lower()).strip()
    text = [wnl.lemmatize(i) for i in text.split ('') if i not in stop_words]
    new_review.append(''.join(text))
return new_review

# actually transforming the datasets
train['review'] = preprocess(train['review'])
test['review'] = preprocess(test['review'])
```

The error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-c0c3b2a57d42> in <module>()
      1 new_review = []
----> 2 for review in text_column:
      3     text = re.sub("@\S+|https?:\S|[^A-Za-z0-9]+",'',str(review).lower()).strip()
      4     text = [wnl.lemmatize(i) for i in text.split ('') if i not in stop_words]
      5     new_review.append(''.join(text))

NameError: name 'text_column' is not defined
```

Please let me know if I could do anything to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: The code should be indented to make it part of the function, it currently isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the body of `preprocess`.

```py
def preprocess(text_column):

    """
    Function:    This function aims to remove links, special 
                 characters, symbols, stop words and thereafter 
                 lemmatise each word in the sentence to transform 
                 the dataset into something more usable for a 
                 machine learning model.
    Input:       A text column
    Returns:     A text column (but transformed)
    """
    new_review = [] 
    for review in text_column:
        text = re.sub("@\S+|https?:\S|[^A-Za-z0-9]+",'',str(review).lower()).strip()
        text = [wnl.lemmatize(i) for i in text.split ('') if i not in stop_words]
        new_review.append(''.join(text))
    return new_review
```